# GCDWebServer 500 error

Tags: swift, gcdwebserver

I try to run GCDWebServer in order to access it from the same device on which it is going to work.

I have following code

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webServer: GCDWebServer?
    var webView: WKWebView?

    let urlpath : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300))
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView!)

        initWebServer()

        let urlString:String = "\(webServer!.serverURL)index.html"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

        webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }

 func initWebServer() {

        webServer = GCDWebServer()
        webServer!.addGETHandlerForBasePath("/", directoryPath: urlpath as String, indexFilename: "index.html", cacheAge: 3600, allowRangeRequests: true)
        webServer!.startWithPort(8080, bonjourName: "GCD Web Server")
        print("Visit \(webServer!.serverURL) in your web browser")
    }
```

In console I have following output

[image]

How to make it work ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? The network request I have made looks completely legit. I notice this issue more, for specific hosts, when the "Debugger" option is on in our XCUITest "Test" schema. The error doesn't tell you which request is invalid either. When there are 10s of requests going on at a time, it's difficult to know which ones are failing.

Answer (score 0):

The log indicates your HTTP request is invalid therefore the 500 error.

Make sure the URL passed to `-loadRequest` is valid (it might be missing a `/` before `index.html` for instance).